# Extract all email addresses from a plain text using C# and insert on different tables database

Tags: c#, mysql

Is there a way to extract all email addresses from a plain text using C#.

For example this string:

```
[id=4068;name=mrgar@yahoo.com]
[id=4078;name=mrrame@gmail.com]
[id=4088;name=mrgio@yahoo.com]
```

return

```
mrgar@yahoo.com, mrrame@gmail.com, mrgio@yahoo.com
```

I need insert into differents MySQL table the string.

First mail address into **dotable_1** and all other mail address into **dotable_2**.

On this example:

1. `mrgar@yahoo.com`,  insert into **dotable_1**;
2. `mrrame@gmail.com`, `mrgio@yahoo.com` , insert into **dotable_2**

How to do this?

My code below.

```
    protected void btnFinal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string exampleTxt = @"[id=4068;name=mrgar@yahoo.com][id=4078;name=mrrame@gmail.com][id=4088;name=mrgio@yahoo.com]";
        string[] emails = identifyEmailAddress(exampleTxt);
        foreach(string s in emails)
        {
            displayLabel.Text += s + "<br />";
        }
    }

    // Return emails with a string array.
    private string[] identifyEmailAddress(string txt)
    {
        const string MatchEmailPattern =@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"; 
        Regex rx = new Regex(MatchEmailPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(txt);

        int noOfMatches = matches.Count;

        string[] result = new string[noOfMatches];

        int i = 0;
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            result[i++] = match.Value.ToString();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, so you have a [working regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cw%2b%28%5b-%2b.%5d%5cw%2b%29*%40%5cw%2b%28%5b-.%5d%5cw%2b%29*%5c.%5cw%2b%28%5b-.%5d%5cw%2b%29*&i=%5bid%3d4068%3bname%3dmrgar%40yahoo.com%5d%5bid%3d4078%3bname%3dmrrame%40gmail.com%5d%5bid%3d4088%3bname%3dmrgio%40yahoo.com%5d). What is the problem? If you mean you need to get the first one, just access it via index, or use `.FirstOrDefault()`. To get the rest, use `.Skip(1)`.

Comment: `identifyEmailAddress()` seems to work as expected. what is the question?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need split the string `mrgar@yahoo.com, mrrame@gmail.com, mrgio@yahoo.com` and insert `mrgar@yahoo.com` on table1 and `mrrame@gmail.com, mrgio@yahoo.com`on table2

Comment: @jonathana I need split the string `mrgar@yahoo.com, mrrame@gmail.com, mrgio@yahoo.com` and insert `mrgar@yahoo.com` on table1 and `mrrame@gmail.com, mrgio@yahoo.com`on table2

Comment: That is what you need, your task. What is the **problem with the code**?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can't split the string `mrgar@yahoo.com, mrrame@gmail.com, mrgio@yahoo.com` for insert into database

Comment: @UncleVince In general, one option is to set a `Dictionary<string,string>` when key is the email and the value is the table name, then iterate the dictionary to insert every key(email) to the desired table(value)

Comment: Ok, the regex is [not an issue](https://ideone.com/VenCf9). You get all the email addresses.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for help. I have see your suggestion but not distinguish from first and other value in string `mrgar@yahoo.com, mrrame@gmail.com, mrgio@yahoo.com`. is only list... I'm sorry don't understand

Comment: See https://ideone.com/wffRCr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if( emails.length >0){

// write EF code / Sql to insert emails[0] into dotable_1;

 for(i=1; i<emails.length-1; i++){

// write EF code / Sql to insert emails[i] into dotable_2;

}

}
```